# Angular 2, Проблема валидации данных и маски ввода

Tags: angular2, валидация, директива

Я реализовал валидацию формы по руководству https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-series-part-5-forms-and-custom-validation/
...

```
            <input class="form-control"
                   type="text"
                   name="phone"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   placeholder="(XXX)-XXX-XXXX"
                   mask=""
                   [disabled]="disabled"
                   [(ngModel)]="candidate.phone"
                   ngControl="phone"/>
```

...

...

```
static phone(control: Control): ValidationResult {

    let URL_REGEXP = /^\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4}$/i;

    if (control.value && (control.value.length <= 5 || !URL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) {

        return {"phone": true};
    }

    return null;
}
```

...

плюс для данного элемента формы я реализовал директиву маски ввода:
http://pastebin.com/wRzHSsVy

Проблема возникает в следующем: при вводе номера телефона сначала срабатывает валидация а потом уже директива маски, таким образом получается что данные которые проверяет валидатор и данные которые форматирует директива маски отличаются, к примеру на валидаторе номер телефона (888)-888-88882 а маска приводит номер к виду (888)-888-8888 но валидатор уже отработал и выдал ошибку до срабатывания маски.

Как можно вызвать валидатор после срабатывания директивы маски ввода?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" [(ngModel)]="myclass.phone" [pattern]="PHONE_PATTERN" [textMask]="{mask: PHONE_MASK}"/>
```

**ts:**

```
static PHONE_PATTERN = /\(\d{3}\)\-\d{3}\-\d{4}/;
static PHONE_MASK = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```